# Attach js file to block in drupaL 7?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I want to attach a JavaScript file to a specific block module. I know i need to add with `drupal_add_js()`, but I'm not sure where to put this code.

If someone could show the code for a JavaScript file with a function that gives a simple `alert()`, I would be thankful.

Comment: Do you actually mean you have a custom block code in your custom module or your block is being added as a standard Drupal block from admin page?

Comment: I've created my own block that containts a form.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your themes pre_process function and then using the Drupal add_js and get_path methods point it in the right direction.

```
hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') .'/js/my_js_file.js');
    ...
}
```